# Compare dataframe column to another dataframe column

Tags: r, apply, grepl

I have a dataframe column containing page paths (let's call it A):

```
pagePath
/text/other_text/123-string1-4571/text.html
/text/other_text/string2/15-some_other_txet.html
/text/other_text/25189-string3/45112-text.html
/text/other_text/text/string4/5418874-some_other_txet.html
/text/other_text/string5/text/some_other_txet-4157/text.html
/text/other_text/123-text-4571/text.html
/text/other_text/125-text-471/text.html
```

And I have another string dataframe column let's call it (B) (the two dataframes are different and they don't have the same number of rows).

Here's an example of my column in dataframe B:

```
names
string1
string11
string4
string3
string2
string10
string5
string100
```

What I want to do is to check if my page paths (A) are containing strings from my other dataframe (B).

I had difficulties because my two dataframes haven't the same length and the data are unorganized.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

I want to have this output as a result:

```
 pagePath                                                  names     exist
/text/other_text/123-string1-4571/text.html                string1   TRUE
/text/other_text/string2/15-some_other_txet.html           string2   TRUE
/text/other_text/25189-string3/45112-text.html             string3   TRUE
/text/other_text/text/string4/5418874-some_other_txet.html string4   TRUE
/text/string5/text/some_other_txet-4157/text.html          string5   TRUE
/text/other_text/123-text-4571/text.html                     NA      FALSE
/text/other_text/125-text-471/text.html                      NA      FALSE
```

If my question needs more clarification, please mention this.

Comment: `A$pagePath[B$pagePath]` ?

Comment: @mtoto I want to chek if my column A contains data from comumn B (data in column A and column B are not equal, but sometimes column A contains data from column B)

Comment: @sarah I think you should check out the match function in R.

Comment: please show an example of `B` and your expected output.

Comment: @mtoto I edited my question and I wrote an example of B.

Comment: thanks, now what would you like to have returned as output?

Comment: @mtoto I added my desired output in the question, thank you.

Comment: thx, only the last two rows in your expected output is not in example `A` now

Comment: @mtoto I corrected this :)

Answer (score 2):

We can generate the `exist` column with `grepl()`

```
# Collapse B$names into one string with "|" 
onestring <- paste(B$names, collapse = "|") 

# Generate new column
A$exist <- grepl(onestring, A$pagePath)
```

Comment: I tried your solution, It gave me this error : `Error in grepl(onestring, A$pagePath) : 
  invalid regular expression`. I think that this due to the `-` character existing in the real data.

Comment: make sure your columns are class `character`

Comment: Now I'm facing another error : ` invalid regular expression, reason Out of memory`

Comment: How big is your data? It should give you the correct output with the example data posted nevertheless.

Comment: the names are about 11000 string and the pages paths are about 37000 :(

Comment: Yes :( , I cheked this now .

Answer (score 2):

Not that nice, since containing a for loop:

```
names <- rep(NA, length(A$pagePath))
exist <- rep(FALSE, length(A$pagePath))

for (name in B$names) {
  names[grep(name, A$pagePath)] <- name
  exist[grep(name, A$pagePath)] <- TRUE
}
```

Comment: Thank's @dotton, I am trying your solution. If It's ok for my case, I'll try to convert the loop for to an apply function :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_extract_all` from `stringr` package but `NA` are replaced with `character(0)` so we have to change it

```
df$names <- as.character(str_extract_all(df$pagePath, "string[0-9]+"))
df$exist <- df$names %in% df1$names
df[df=="character(0)"] <- NA
df
#                                                 pagePath       names   exist
#1                  /text/other_text/123-string1-4571/text.html string1  TRUE
#2             /text/other_text/string2/15-some_other_txet.html string2  TRUE
#3               /text/other_text/25189-string3/45112-text.html string3  TRUE
#4   /text/other_text/text/string4/5418874-some_other_txet.html string4  TRUE
#5 /text/other_text/string5/text/some_other_txet-4157/text.html string5  TRUE
#6                     /text/other_text/123-text-4571/text.html    <NA> FALSE
#7                      /text/other_text/125-text-471/text.html    <NA> FALSE
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(pagePath = structure(c(1L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("/text/other_text/123-string1-4571/text.html", 
"/text/other_text/123-text-4571/text.html", "/text/other_text/125-text-471/text.html", 
"/text/other_text/25189-string3/45112-text.html", "/text/other_text/string2/15-some_other_txet.html", 
"/text/other_text/string5/text/some_other_txet-4157/text.html", 
"/text/other_text/text/string4/5418874-some_other_txet.html"), class = "factor")), .Names = "pagePath", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
dput(df1)
structure(list(names = structure(c(1L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 
3L), .Label = c("string1", "string10", "string100", "string11", 
"string2", "string3", "string4", "string5"), class = "factor")), .Names = "names", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: my problem is that the two columns have'nt the same length

Comment: It should work though. The data I used is the same as the one you shared

Comment: @sarah also you should convert your data frame to character as having factors for paths does not make sense.

Comment: thank you. I'll try this and I will let my feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using apply:

```
df$exist <- apply( df,1,function(x){as.logical(grepl(x[2],x[1]))} )
```